# IE 10 Font Issues - failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

I am creating a web app and using custom fonts along with fontawesome. I am getting this below error
    CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable. 
    305D82_3_0.ttf

```
CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable. 
glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
```

My CSS is

```
  @charset "UTF-8";



@font-face
    {
      font-family: 'c_regular';
      src: url("305D82_3_0.eot") format("embedded-opentype");
      src: url("305D82_3_0.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("305D82_3_0.woff2") format("woff2"), url("305D82_3_0.woff") format("woff"), url("305D82_3_0.ttf") format("truetype");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
    @font-face
    {
      font-family: 'e_bold';
      src: url("fsemeric-bold-webfont.eot") format("embedded-opentype");
      src: url("fsemeric-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("fsemeric-bold-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"), url("fsemeric-bold-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("fsemeric-bold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("fsemeric-bold-webfont.svg#e_bold") format("svg");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the following:

```
<staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</staticContent>
```

under

```
<system.webServer>
```

in web.config.

Original source: https://medium.com/@zikaitoh/css3111-and-css3114-issue-640e7d5e9163